# Very simple 301 redirection, but not working as desired

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I want to redirect this link
http://www.example.com/index_cpath-19.html to http://www.example.com

I am using this approach

```
Redirect 301 /index_cpath-19\.html  http://www.example.com/
```

It redirects fine but it generates following link in URL Bar
http://www.example.com/?index_cpath-19.html

Please suggest me how to remove this ?index_cpath-19.html from http://www.example.com/?index_cpath-19.html to make it look http://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked perfect for my problem.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index_cpath-19.html$  http://www.example.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index_cpath-19.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/? [R=301,L]
```